# Windows で npm install を実行するとエラーが発生する

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

現在githubからプログラムソースをローカル環境にcloneし，npm installを実行しました。
しかし「'cp' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。」というエラーが生じました。ソースコードはおそらくlinux or unix環境にて作成されたものですが，私の実行環境はwindows11のためこのエラーが生じたと思います。環境変数を通せばいいと思うのですが，環境変数を設定するpathがわかりません。わかる方ご教授お願いします。

Comment: githubで公開されているものでしたら、Windows環境へインストールする際の方法について、どこかに説明がないでしょうか。cpは確かにunix系OSで一般的なコピーコマンドで、Windowsには標準では含まれていません。なので、環境変数PATHを設定したところでどうしようもありません。回避方法がないわけではないと思いますが、まずは作った方が想定されている方法がないか確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。作った方の説明書きなどを参照していたのですが，実行環境などは提示されていませんでした。なので結局は仮想環境のunix系osを利用し，npm installすることにしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/4236)です。

> ソースコードはおそらくlinux or unix環境にて作成されたものですが，

想像しても何も得られません。
そのソフトウェアのドキュメントを参照すればわかることです。ドキュメントの読み方がわからないのであれば対象のソフトウェアを提示すべきです。対象のソフトウェアを秘匿したいのであれば自己解決するしかありません。

> 私の実行環境はwindows11のためこのエラーが生じたと思います。

想像に想像を重ねても何も得られません。
作成環境が何であるかは重要ではなく、そのソフトウェアの動作環境を確認しましょう。
Windowsに対応していないのであれば、Windowsには対応していません（小泉構文）。

> 環境変数を通せばいいと思うのですが，

想像に想像、更なる想像を重ねても虚しいだけです。
何の情報もなく、環境変数で解決するか誰にもわからないです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。あの後自分で試行錯誤したのですが，なんとか自己解決することができました。たしかに提示している情報が圧倒的に少なかったです。